# Unexplainable leading space only in first value when reading from csv

Tags: python, csv, io

I am reading some values from a .csv and for some reason a space is being appended to the start of the first value. Does anyone know why this may be?

INPUT:

[image]

```
    with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:

        host = row[0]
        destination = row[1]
        port = row[2]
        print("HOST")
        print(host)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Note that the input.csv does not have any spaces at the beginning of the first value. Also using lstrip() does not seem to fix this.

Comment: `print(ascii(host))` and show the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (U+FEFF) code point and is used as a byte-order mark (BOM) for UTF16- and UTF32-encoded files and a signature for UTF-8-encoded files.  It isn't removed by `.strip()`.  Using `open('input.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')` removes the signature if present, assuming your .CSV is encoded in UTF-8.  Other options are `utf16` and `utf32`.  They require the BOM and remove it as well, but most likely it is UTF-8.

Use `print(ascii(host))` to see what the character actually is:

```
>>> host = '\ufeffBob'
>>> print(x)
 Bob
>>> print(ascii(x))
'\ufeffBob'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:

    host = row[0]
    host = host.strip() #  choo off whitespace
    destination = row[1]
    port = row[2]
    print("HOST")
    print(host)
```

---

side by Note:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
```

skipinitialspace: If set to True, any white space immediately following the delimiter is ignored.

Comment: @OamarKanji, is this the First Value only `HOST Ben` ? can you show the desired result please.

Comment: There are three columns in the csv: Host, Destination, Port but only the value in the very first row of the very first column is effected by this

Comment: I have now included a screen shot of the input csv in the question

Comment: Okay, what about trying like `host = row[0].strip()` or  in next line  `host=host.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:

        host = row[0]
        destination = row[1]
        port = row[2]
        print("HOST")
        print(host) #  Remove spaces by treating strings
        print(host.strip()) # Default is a blank character
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working even though I dont see why it wouldnt work